# Passing JSon Objects over the internet?

Tags: java, json, apache, http

I'm writing two applications that need to be able to pass data back and forth over the internet.  I understand how to read and write using JSON objects, but am now wondering what the best way to pass this data is?

I have an apache server setup and I tried to simply write to a file in my public_html folder using my server URL, but obviously java doesn't let you write to files over URL so I'm a bit stuck now.

Is there anyway to do this without having to write my own server?

**More explanation in case my question is confusing:**

I have java application A running on machine A and application B running on machine B.

I want to be able to write a Json Object:

```
{"testString":"helloWorld"}
```

from Machine A, and have the application on machine B read this object.

I tried using a BufferedWriter to write to http://MyServerURL.com/MyJsonFile.txt
This gives me an error as I can't write to a URL

I can however read from the file using a URL and data input stream, so if there's some other way to allow java to write to a file over URL, I already know how to do the reading.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can write to an URL. You can do it with a HTTP POST (or PUT). Several good libraries are available to help you with this.

If you use a REST way of working you can put your JSON in the body of the request. 
see https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4313

Alternatively you can have some parameter see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49